# How can we use multiple ConstraintProviders, when using the springboot optaplanner-spring-boot-starter

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner

optaplanner-spring-boot-starter discovers the ContraintProvider automatically, without a solverConfig.xml, so if we want to use multiple constrantProviders for different problems, **like for example**
*problem A, needs to use problemAContraintProvider and problem B, needs to use ProblemBContraintProvider*, is there any Qualifier kind of annotation which i can use and tell the solverManger to use specific ConstraintProvider implementation

```
public class ProblemAConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] { 
                typeMatch(constraintFactory),
                timeSlotMatch(constraintFactory),
                };
    }
}

public class ProblemBConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] { 
                checkId(constraintFactory),
    
                };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a `solverConfig.xml` to overrides the default behavior of looking for the `ConstraintProvider` class (and then fail fasting because it finds two).

Add `src/main/resources/solverConfig.xml` (file location can be tailored with in application.properties) and have it include something like:

```
<solver>
  <scoreDirectoryFactory>
    <constraintProviderClass>...FirstConstraintProvider</>
  </scoreDirectoryFactory>
</solver>
```

But as Radovan pointed out: we don't support multiple SolverManager/solverConfig injections yet in the same Spring Boot app. That is an API gap.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no; similarly to the answer in [can we use multiple @PlanningSolution classes and multiple SolverManager in Springboot optaplanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63715928/can-we-use-multiple-planningsolution-classes-and-multiple-solvermanager-in-spri/63736367#63736367), each type of a planning problem requires a new solver configuration which defines the `constraintProviderClass`.

The `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter` supports only a single solver configuration and thus only a single type of a planning problem.