# can we use multiple @PlanningSolution classes and multiple SolverManager in Springboot optaplanner

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, optaplanner

For Springboot application using optaplanner-spring-boot-starter, the cloudbalancing problem solution works fine with one planning solution and solverManager similar to
https://github.com/DuncanDoyle/optaplanner-sbs-cloud-balancing/tree/master/optaplanner-sbs , but when multiple planning solutions are defined and called using a solverManager it throws an error

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'solverFactory' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/optaplanner/spring/boot/autoconfigure/OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'solverFactory'
> parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'solverConfig' defined in class path resource
> [org/optaplanner/spring/boot/autoconfigure/OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig]: Factory
> method 'solverConfig' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple classes ([class
> com.test.model.PRCaseAssignment, class
> com.test.model.CaseAssignment]) found with a
> @PlanningSolution annotation.

How can we define multiple @PlanningSolution classes and call using the solverManager, are there any kind of Qualifiers which needs to be annotated? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I ask what is the use case for having multiple solution classes?

The `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter` supports only a single solver configuration and thus only a single solution class. So does the `SolverManager` API: you can submit multiple planning problems to the `SolverManager`, but they have to be of the same type (solution class) and share the same solver configuration. To submit a planning problem of a different type, you have to create a new instance of the `SolverManager`. See the [documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#solverManager) on how to create an instance of the `SolverManager` manually.

Comment: Yes, this is true and **it's an API gap**. We need to figure out a way with Qualifiers to allow multiple SolverConfigs/SolverManagers to co-exist, both in Spring Boot and Quarkus.

Comment: Related question by same author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63712863/how-can-we-use-multiple-constraintproviders-when-using-the-springboot-optaplann/63737303#63737303