# Is it possible to solve planning problems of a different types with timeFold/optaplanner with Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus, optaplanner, timefold

I'm quite new in optaplanner/timeFold and I've faced with problem like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step ai.timefold.solver.quarkus.deployment.TimefoldProcessor#recordAndRegisterBeans threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple classes ([Model1.domain.Solution1Table, Model2.domain.Solution2Table]) found with a @PlanningSolution annotation.
```

I have two different xml-configurations in src\main\resources for each solutionClass.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63715928/can-we-use-multiple-planningsolution-classes-and-multiple-solvermanager-in-spri) I should create a new instance of the SolverManager to solve second problem, but I don't understand is it possible to do that with Quarkus.

Comment: This is a known issue (feature gap). I've created [an issue for it](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/351) to track it.

Comment: @Geoffrey De Smet
So the only option I have now, is to merge two problems in one, isn't it?

Comment: That's worse, that will affect the solving speed and quality a lot negatively.

Workaround: You can build the SolverConfigs and SolverManagers manually for now, see the hello-world example in timefold-quickstarts.

Comment: @Geoffrey De Smet Do you mean without Quarkus?

Comment: With Quarkus, but you might need to exclude the `timefold-quarkus` module for it to not fail fast... which means the jackson support for Score also disappears....

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Sorry, I am not good in deployment at all. Do you mean I should add quarkus.arc.exclude-types=ai.timefold.solver.quarkus to application.properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I should just replace `timefold-solver-quarkus-benchmark` with `timefold-solver-core` in dependency in pom.xml.