# How to exclude quarkus from an external package (ai.timefold.solver.quarkus)?

Tags: maven, quarkus, timefold

I have an error like that

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step ai.timefold.solver.quarkus.deployment.TimefoldProcessor#recordAndRegisterBeans threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple classes ([Model1.domain.Solution1Table, Model2.domain.Solution2Table]) found with a @PlanningSolution annotation.
```

And I've got [a piece of advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77315471/is-it-possible-to-solve-planning-problems-of-a-different-types-with-timefold-opt?noredirect=1#comment136305547_77315471) to exclude timefold-quarkus module.

I've tried to remove this module through application.properties

```
quarkus.arc.exclude-types=ai.timefold.solver.quarkus**,ai.timefold.solver.quarkus*,ai.timefold.solver.quarkus
```

I've tried to remove this module through pom.xml
At first:

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-sourcepath</arg>
            <arg>doesnotexist</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/ai/timefold/solver/quarkus/*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

then:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/ai/timefold/solver/quarkus/*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

At last:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.timefold.solver</groupId>
        <artifactId>timefold-solver-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${version.ai.timefold.solver}</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>ai.timefold.solver</groupId>
            <artifactId>timefold-solver-quarkus</artifactId>  
        </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
```

Nothing helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to remove Quarkus from Timefold Solver's Quarkus support module.

I understand what the original advice was trying to say, but it was perhaps not very clear. The point of the original advice was not to use the `timefold-solver-quarkus` module *at all* and use the basic `timefold-solver-core` module instead. Whether that is feasible in your case, I do not know.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea where timefold-solver-quarkus was used. In my java-classes it definitely wasn't imported. Do you have any advice how can I trace that?

Comment: Your Maven or Gradle project most likely depends on `timefold-solver-quarkus`.